# MySQL Query with specific WHERE rules

Tags: mysql

**Hello Stackers**

I'm having another Question, this time about the **deprecated** MySQL. I'm having the following Query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_notificaties WHERE username = '". $user['id'] ."' AND userstatus = 'unseen' OR userstatus = 'priority' ")or die(mysql_error());
```

This will select all notifictions, even when the WHERE username value isn't correct. However, I Want that only the notifications with the right `user id` will be requested, but, only the ones with the userstatus `unseen` OR *priority*. How can I do that? Is that even possible with MySQL?

A Small sidenote, I Know that MySQL is deprecated, but I need to change the whole CMS for that, which I will do later in time.

Comment: `MySQL is deprecated`... oh, I haven't knew. Why? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket around `OR` condition.

```
SELECT * FROM cms_notificaties WHERE username = '". $user['id'] ."' AND ( userstatus = 'unseen' OR userstatus = 'priority' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872180/how-exactly-does-using-or-in-a-mysql-statement-differ-with-without-parentheses) where it says that OR has lower operator precedence than AND. So you need to use parentheses, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_notificaties WHERE username = '". $user['id'] ."' AND ( userstatus = 'unseen' OR userstatus = 'priority' )
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, this indeed fixed the problem. Does this work similar in MySQLi?