# MySQL query runs out of memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a system in which a store is an account and customers shop in those stores.  There is a table that stores many-to-many association of customers and stores.  The key attributes of that table are accountid, customerid and last_visit_date.  For a set of accountids, I need to find the most recent visit of each customer.  I have a query that works perfectly but seems to be inefficient because it runs out of memory for about 21000 customers.

```
SELECT ac.customerId FROM account_customer ac 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT customerId, max(last_visit_date) AS 
                     LastVisitDate FROM account_customer 
                  WHERE accountId in        
                     (311,307,318,320,321,322,323,332,347,439,519,630,634,643) 
                 GROUP BY customerId) grouped_ac 
     ON ac.customerId = grouped_ac.customerId 
          AND ac.last_visit_date = grouped_ac.LastVisitDate 
          AND ac.last_visit_date <= '2016-10-18' 
          OR ac.last_visit_date is null
```

When I run the above query, it gives me the correct result for a smaller dataset but for larger dataset, I get memory error.  I am not even talking about a very large set - just around 20,000 + customers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your PHP code.

Comment: Run an `EXPLAIN` plan in MySQL for the query. It may hint at a missing index.

Comment: right now I am just trying to run the raw query that I posted directly in mysql server using mysql workbench and running out of memory there.

Comment: @WaqarSadiq stick `EXPLAIN ` on the front of it and post the results.

Comment: I did that and it gave me back three rows but did not indicate any full table scans or anything like that.

Comment: Please add it to your question. It is just guesswork at answering otherwise.

Comment: If your server runs out of memory it's configured incorrectly. Check the size of your InnoDB buffer pools. Maybe they're too generous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you possibly mean

```
ac.customerId = grouped_ac.customerId 
AND ac.last_visit_date = grouped_ac.LastVisitDate 
and (ac.last_visit_date <= '2016-10-18' or ac.last_visit_date is null)
```

I think without the parentheses, the query may be returning all records there the last_visit_date is null.

Take a look at the answer to [How exactly does using OR in a MySQL statement differ with/without parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872180/how-exactly-does-using-or-in-a-mysql-statement-differ-with-without-parentheses).

Comment: You are right.  That is what was happening.  Thanks.

Comment: Was that causing the memory issue, because so many records were coming back?

Comment: I think so.  Once I put those parenthesis around - it worked fine without memory exhaustion.