# How to Use AND and OR in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i want to create a search in my web. in search form i have Category and Input query for search. for example in category im choice **jmovies** and in input query im type keyword for **ashi**.

my code

```
SELECT * 
FROM master_post 
WHERE category = 'jmovies' 
    AND master_post_name LIKE '%ashi%' 
    OR altname LIKE '%ashi%'
```

so category = **jmovies** and keyword = **ashi**.

for example i have table like this

```
category     master_post_name    alt_name
===========  ==================  ===============
JMovies      ashi_include_1      not_include
JMovies      ashi_include_2      not_include
JMovies      ashi_include_3      not_include
JMovies      not_include         ashi_include_1
JMovies      not_include         not_include
Drama        ashi_in_drama       ashi_include_2
```

if i run with that code result is

```
category     master_post_name    alt_name
===========  ==================  ===============
JMovies      ashi_include_1      not_include
JMovies      ashi_include_2      not_include
JMovies      ashi_include_3      not_include
JMovies      not_include         ashi_include_1
Drama        ashi_in_drama       ashi_include_2
```

the problem is, cause im choice **jmovies**, category **drama** should not be in my result, even if drama have **ashi** in **master_post** or **alt_name**.

result must be like this

```
category     master_post_name    alt_name
===========  ==================  ===============
JMovies      ashi_include_1      not_include
JMovies      ashi_include_2      not_include
JMovies      ashi_include_3      not_include
JMovies      not_include         ashi_include_1
```

even if im choice **jmovies** and not fill **input keyword** result is not showing only jmovies but it showing **drama** too.

NOTE: **alt_name** and **master_post_name** have same keyword.

Comment: Isn't this just a case of adding some brackets to your query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: brackets? i hope you mean parentheses @Chris

Comment: :-) https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/parentheses-and-brackets

Comment: ah i see, i know that must using "(" and ")" but i dont know how to use it and what name that is, so that is parentheses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you may try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM master_post 
WHERE category = 'jmovies' AND (master_post_name LIKE '%ashi%' OR altname LIKE '%ashi%')
```

I suspect that the "problem" here is the fact that the AND operator has a greater precedence than the OR operator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but give parenthesis a go:

```
SELECT * FROM master_post 
WHERE category = 'jmovies' AND (master_post_name LIKE '%ashi%' OR altname LIKE '%ashi%')
```

see this answer: [How exactly does using OR in a MySQL statement differ with/without parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872180/how-exactly-does-using-or-in-a-mysql-statement-differ-with-without-parentheses)